# Default inputType of EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose I have an EditText in my layout.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    />
```

We can set the inputType for this EditText as text, number, phone, textPassword, etc. What will be the inputType of the EditText by default?

Answer (score 19):

After some research found that default Edittext **InputType** will be `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`

Which is Hex:0x20001
or Decimal: 131073

Comment: I believe this answer is correct because an `EditText` with no explicit `android:inputType` attribute will be multi-line (i.e. will wrap long text and expand height).

Comment: How do you know? Do you have a link to the source code or documentation?

Comment: I can confirm this is correct. This can be easily verified by `getInputType` on a new EditText and it is the bitwise OR of 131072 (`TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`) and 1 (`TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`)

Answer (score 12):

It will be text with no special options.  So just   TYPE_CLASS_TEXT

Answer (score 1):

Just plain old text. Corresponds to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL.

Answer (score 0):

you mean default keyboard is the device default keyboard if you dont specified **inputType** to Edittext in xml.Hope this helps you to understand.

Answer (score -5):

By Default it will be always:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

Comment: How to confirm this answer?

Comment: Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.or Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

Comment: Will do if you prove your answer. :)